# Android Instrumentation Test Runner being "Force Stopped' when debugging

Tags: android, android-testing

I am able to run all of my automated tests via the Android IDE, but I am unable to step through them in Debug mode.

Looking through the logs, I see that the ActivityManager "force stops" the test process.

Any suggestions as to how I can approach this problem?

```
2023-01-23 09:44:25.000 24226-24266 TestRunner              com.datmedia.mytests.test            I  run started: 1 tests
2023-01-23 09:44:25.022 24226-24266 TestRunner              com.datmedia.mytests.test            I  started: setProperty(com.datmedia.mytests.TestMyKotlinClass)
2023-01-23 09:44:25.102   425-17752 ActivityManager         system_process                       I  Force stopping com.datmedia.mytests.test appid=10142 user=0: from pid 24270
2023-01-23 09:44:25.103   425-17752 ActivityManager         system_process                       I  Killing 24226:com.datmedia.mytests.test/u0a142 (adj 0): stop com.datmedia.mytests.test due to from pid 24270
2023-01-23 09:44:25.106   425-17752 ActivityManager         system_process                       W  Crash of app com.datmedia.mytests.test running instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.datmedia.mytests.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}
2023-01-23 09:44:25.107   425-17752 ActivityManager         system_process                       I  Force stopping com.datmedia.mytests.test appid=10142 user=0: finished inst
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling "Run Android Instrumented Tests using Gradle" in Android Studio -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Testing"

This worked for me while I had a similar issue in Android Studio Giraffe when I stumbled upon this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77271279/4533010