# Tests not running on Android Studio : "Tests Cancelled 0 passed"

Tags: android-studio

#### What happened?

I'm facing an issue where I'm unable to run tests in Android Studio. When I try to run the tests, the console shows "Tests Cancelled 0 passed" and nothing happens. I even created a new project based on the default code, but the issue persists. I'm not sure if this is a bug or an implementation fault.

I've searched for a solution on Stack Overflow but couldn't find any resolution. Could anyone here provide me with a workaround that could solve this issue?

##### Steps to reproduce:

Open Android Studio
Create a new project (if not already created)
Create a test class and add some test cases

Try to run the tests

**Expected result:**
The tests should run and show the test results in the console.

**Actual result:**
The console shows "Tests Cancelled 0 passed" and nothing happens.

**Environment:**

Android Studio version: [Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Beta 1]
Operating system: [MacOS 13.3.1 (22E261)]

**Additional details:**

> It happens only for Instrumented test;

I've tried running tests in a newly created project but the issue persists.
I've searched for a solution on Stack Overflow but couldn't find any resolution.
I'm not sure if this is a bug or an implementation fault.
Any help or workaround would be greatly appreciated.

#### Relevant logcat output

```bash
java.text.SimpleDateFormat@4f76f1a0: Launching Tests in 'com.shaileshmishra.appnews' on 'Pixel 5 API 30.
Running tests
$ adb shell am instrument -w -m    -e package com.shaileshmishra.appnews -e debug false com.shaileshmishra.appnews.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner



Machine OS:

Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Beta 1
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.9923731, built on April 12, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.5-9884540 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.3.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 12
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.experimental.ui=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.github.setial (4.0.2)
```

Comment: Hey have you found any solution on it ? I am also facing same issue. please help me if you have resolved it.

Comment: Yeah same here, on MacOS 13.3.1 I ended up downgrading to Flamingo; tests are working again

Comment: I think I'm encountering the same problem too, I've create a bug report here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/304343840

Answer (score 9):

I was able to fix this issue on my machine (macOS Sonoma) by enabling "Run Android Instrumented Tests using Gradle" in Android Studio -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Testing"

Comment: I tried it with and without enabling "Run Android Instrumented Tests using Gradle" in Android Studio -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Testing" 
But it's not fixing the issue.

Comment: yes it worked after i checked this :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it took a day to resolve this issue but eventually I did by upgrading the gradle file. I am attaching a screenshot please have a look. Note: **I didn't *uncheck* the option in File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Testing > Run Android Instrumented Tests Using Gradle.**

[image]